# Norm equivalence preserves canonical evaluation map and thus reflexivity

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, banach-spaces, dual-spaces, reflexive-space

I'm trying to prove below result (that I'm not sure if it's true!). Could you have a check on my attempt?

> **Theorem:** Let $E = F$ be non-empty sets. Let $|\cdot|, [\cdot]$ be norms on $E, F$ respectively such that they are [equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Equivalent_norms). If $(E, |\cdot|)$ is [reflexive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_space#Reflexive_Banach_spaces), then so is $(F, [\cdot])$.

**My attempt:**  Let $(E^{*},  |\cdot|_*), (F^{*}, [\cdot]_*)$ be the duals of $(E, |\cdot|)$ and $(F, [\cdot])$ respectively.

Equivalent norms induce the same topology and thus the same set of continuous linear functionals. Hence $E^{*} = F^{*}$. Notice that $|\cdot|, [\cdot]$ are equivalent if and only if  $|\cdot|_*, [\cdot]_*$ are equivalent. This is due to
$$
|x| = \max_{f \in E^*} \frac{f(x)}{|f|_*} \quad \text{and} \quad |f|_* = \sup_{x \in E} \frac{f(x)}{|x|}.
$$

Let $(E^{**},  |\cdot|_{**}), (F^{**}, [\cdot]_{**})$ be the biduals of $(E, |\cdot|)$ and $(F, [\cdot])$ respectively. It follows from $|\cdot|_*, [\cdot]_*$ are equivalent that $|\cdot|_{**}, [\cdot]_{**}$ are equivalent. Again, we have $E^{**} = F^{**}$.

Let $J_E:E \to E^{**}$ and $J_F : F \to F^{**}$ be the canonical evaluation maps. We have $J_E$ is surjective. We have
$$
\langle J_E x, f \rangle := f(x)  \quad \text{and} \quad\langle J_F x, g \rangle := g(x) \quad \forall f \in E^*, \forall g \in F^*.
$$

It follows that $J_E = J_F$ and thus $J_F$ is also surjective. This completes the proof.

Comment: This looks good. I'm not sure why you doubt proof, let alone the the result!

Comment: @TheoBendit I thought that if this result is true then someone may have asked a question on MSE. However, I only found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3948717/does-norm-equivalence-preserve-the-reflexivity-of-banach-spaces) which does not contain a positive answer.